# Overlaying bitmaps and positioning

Tags: java, android, canvas

I'm using the following code in order to overlay 2 bitmaps:

```
private Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, new Matrix(), null);
        return bmOverlay;
    }
```

What it does is the following : placing the second bitmap on top of the first one, in top left corner.

My question is how could I place the second bitmap in center bottom? Thank you :)

Comment: simply change the `Matrix`, you can call `postTranslate()` or `setRectToRect()`

Comment: @pskink - thanks for the brief reply. Haven't worked with matrices and canvases so far so I definitely have no clue on how to do that.

Right now I am trying to add some float values for the second bitmap. I saw drawBitmap can also take 2 float values which represent floating left point and top. I guess that could also be a solution, right?  Floating left point would be bmp1.getWidth / 2 and floating top bmp1.getHeight

Comment: well , try it, learn, experiment

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 private Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
        int centerX = (int) bmp1.getWidth()/2;
        int centerY = (int) bmp1.getHeight()/2;
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, centerX, centerY, null);
        return bmOverlay;
    }
```

Comment: This is adding the second bitmap in the center of the first one. I want it center bottom.

Comment: change centerY to bottomY = (int) bmp1.getHeight();